# Avoid exposing static variable for a default function argument

Tags: c++

I have a function `foo()` that updates a global `CAtlList`. Now I want to reuse `foo` to update another list. Currently I achieve this using a default argument.

```
 //header.h
 extern CAtlList<data> globalList;
 void foo(CAtlList<data> &somelist = globalList);

 //file1.cpp
 CAtlList<data> globalList;
 void foo(CAtlList<data> &somelist)
 {
    //update somelist
 }

 //file2.cpp
 #include "header.h" 
 foo();

and 

 CAtlList<data> anotherList;
 foo(anotherList);
//use anotherList
```

But for the default scenario `foo` takes `globalList` by reference, which means `globalList` must be visible at the point of declaration. I had to expose and add an extern declaration of `globalList` for that to happen.

I'd rather not expose it, is it at all possible?

Comment: You want foo to be more general or not?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes i want it to be general.

Comment: @miradulo What could be an alternative for this?

Comment: All what can be answered here is: It depends! :-) Sorry, but using globals and even as default parameter is good or bad, but only if environment is known. On a first view I would dislike your solution, but if it fits to your needs... why not.

Comment: A (much) better design is to avoid using globals altogether. When this is not an option, your design is as good as it gets.

Comment: @miradulo Also what can go wrong in using default like this?

Comment: Tell us more about this global. Did it have internal linkage and you had to externalize it? Is that what makes you worried?

Comment: @StoryTeller..Yes the definition of the global is in different compilation unit.In the header file i declare the prototype of `foo` as taking default argument for which i had to `extern` the global in header.Also it is not making sense to me to take reference to a global variable.

Comment: Can you add the details about making the global extern instead of static to the question? It makes it answerable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I have edited the question.

Comment: another way (not necessary better) is to overload

Comment: @user3819404 - Well, I edited it too, to better explain what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an overload, not a default parameter.

```
void foo();
void foo(CAtlList<data> &somelist);
```

It costs you 4 short lines of code in the `.cpp`: The body of the parameterless `foo` calling the 1-parameter `foo` with the correct argument.  That's the total cost to get the expressiveness you desire.  A default parameter is not the tool for your job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you can avoid declaring a variable that's referenced as a default. However, you could simply overload the function:

```
 //file1.h
 void foo();
 void foo(CAtlList<data> &somelist);

 //file1.cpp
 #include "file2.h"

 CAtlList<data> globalList; // Local scope only

 void foo(CAtlList<data> &somelist)
 {
    //update somelist
 }

 void foo()
 {
    foo(globalList);
 }
```

A more modern way is to use the 'optional' class that's part of the C++ library:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

```
//file1.h
#include <optional>
void foo(optional<CAtlList<data>> &somelist);

//file1.cpp
#include "file1.h"

CAtlList<data> globalList; // Local scope only

void foo(optional<CAtlList<data>> &somelist){
   if (somelist.has_value()) { /* update somelist */ }
   else { /* update globalList */ }
}
```

However, I suspect that this will break the existing dependencies. If there are few and easy to fix, this is probably the way.

The other comments are also correct. You should try and avoid the use of global state wherever possible - its a symptom of poor design.